# Conditionally modify global variable

Tags: python

I'd like to do something like this, but I get a SyntaxWarning and it doesn't work as expected

```
RAWR = "hi"
def test(bool):
    if bool:
        RAWR = "hello"   # make RAWR a new variable, don't reference global in this function
    else:
        global RAWR
        RAWR = "rawr"    # reference global variable in this function
    print RAWR           # if bool, use local, else use global (and modify global)
```

How do I get this to work? Passing in True or False modifies the global variable.

Comment: A `SyntaxWarning`? You probably mean a syntax error. You cannot arbitrarily name something global, no.

Comment: you shouldn't use bool as an argument name because it's a reserved word in python. It's a global function that returns the boolean equivalent of its arguments.

Comment: @Andbdrew It's not reserved, but yes you shouldn't shadow that name.

Comment: @MartijnPieters No, there is actually a `SyntaxWarning`, enabled by default, which warns about assignment to a variable which is declared `global` after that assignment.

Comment: No, there actually is a `SytaxError`. To whit, `SyntaxError: name 'RAWR' is assigned to before global declaration`

Comment: @delnan: Golly, I learned something new today. Never coded anything that produced one. :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters Me neither, I had to check and was surprised too :)

Comment: @veredesmarald Are you sure it says **...Error**? And which Python version is this? On Python 3.2, I get that exact message, but as a **...Warning**.

Comment: @Andbdrew I'm not just used it here as an example :-)

Comment: @delnan Yep it's a versioning thing, `SyntaxError` on 2.7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot. Within a scope, a specific name refers either to a local variable, or to a non-local (e.g. global, or from an outer function) variable. Not both. The `global RAWR` line makes `RAWR` a global for the entire scope (that's why you get a warning, it doesn't do what you think it does), just like assignment to a variable makes it local for the entire scope. Edit: Thanks to veredesmarald, we now know it is in fact a syntax error in Python 2. This half of my answer only applies to Python 3 apparently.

You should just use a differently-named local variable, and in the branch where you want to "promote" it to a global, set the global *and* the local variable. (Or just don't use globals at all.)

Comment: globals are good if you have a variable which holds a large amount of data and you don't want to duplicate this data across functions so as to conserve memory

Comment: @mulllhausen Only applicable if the data is constant and immutable, but yes. Which does not apply to OP's use case.

Comment: @delnan agreed its not relevant to this question. i was responding to xavier's statement "at all".

Answer (score 2):

The only easy way you can go would be

```
RAWR = "hi"
def test(newone):
    if newone:
        lR = "hello"   # make RAWR a new variable, don't reference global in this function
    else:
        global RAWR
        lR = RAWR      # reference global variable in this function
    print lR           # if bool, use local, else use global (and modify global)
    # modify lR and then
    if not newone:
        RAWR = lR
```

Another way, however, could be to abuse the concept of classes and objects to your purposes.

```
class store_RAWR(object):
    RAWR = "hi"
    def __init__(self, new): self.RAWR = new

def test(newone):
    if newone:
        myR = store_RAWR("hello") # get a (temporary) object with a different string
    else:
        myR = store_RAWR # set the class, which is global.
    # now modify myR.RAWR as you need
```

But this requires other program parts which use the global name to be changed as well.